# Setting default values for slicers when no option is selected Power Bi

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

I have a report where a user can filter and compare his/her company to others. 
For now I have 8 bar charts that are filtered by 8 slicers (so users can choose what ratio or value to show in the corresponding bar chart).

However, for ease of use for the final user, I would like a "standard" ratio or value for each different bar chart. For example I would like for chart 1 to show revenue, chart 2 to show profit, etc..
This is so that whenever a user is fine by the standard values he does not have to change the filters. 
If a user would like to change the values/ ratio's for any give chart he or she could change the filter.

Is there a way this can be done in power Bi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible but it also depends on how you switch the shown values.

If you want to use only the visual objects you can:

1. Save the report as you want it, when it gets published to PowerBI service it will keep the filters as they were when you published the report.
2. If the slicer is of type "List" or "Dropdown", you can also set SelectionControls -> Enable "SingleSelect" (if appropriate for your use case), this will force the slicer to always have one value. For the default one use the same instruction in point 1.

If inside the visuals you are using a measure with SWITCH, you can also set a default value, but for that I need to see the current formula.

Comment: Thanks ! Did exactly what I wanted to do, was thinking the solution would be harder than it actually is